# Why can't IntelliJ scala plugin pickup my dependencies?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using intellij 11 ultimate, using the scala plugin.

Most of my code has red highlights everywhere, meaning IntelliJ cannot properly resolve the keywords.

For example, I added the amazon aws depenency (using sbt) and 1/2 my code is red, and intellisence doesn't work either.

Note:  This is happening for many many libraries I am using, and it is a real pain.  I am building using the terminal using the sbt command also.

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong?  Or is it just a fact of live using scala with intellij?

**Update:**

I do see this message sometimes:

**File '/path/to/app/web/built.sbt' seems to be SBT build file, but there is no external project related to it.  Import the corresponing project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart" often helps to prevent IntelliJ from showing non-existing Scala errors.

I have no IntelliJ 11, so I do not know if this exists in your Intellij version.

Comment: I do have that, I am using version 11 also.  Trying it now.  Update -- Ok it looks like it works, I'll just confirm and response back.  This is great!

Comment: btw, I added a new sbt module, and I see the folder in IntelliJ.  When I add a new file, I don't see 'scala class'.  How do I tell that this project is a scala project?